# Хеширование паролей javaEE

Tags: javascript, java, md5, j2ee

Ребята, стоит задача - хранить пароли в зашифрованном виде. Насколько я понял, пароли можно хешировать md5 + соль. Ок, пробовал это все сделать на сервере(для начала только в md5 без соли), использую spring security ,ну вообще, лажа какая-то получается, пароль то хешируется, но мне постоянно надо следить, когда я от клиента получаю пароль - его обязательно надо хешировать в md5 - не очень удобно, то есть от клиента мне настоящий пароль приходит. Теперь задаюсь вопросом, не легче ли это все провернуть на клиенте ? То есть где лучше хешировать пароль на бэкенде или клиенте ? Если на клиенте подскажите как именно провернуть все это, я в js не силён.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: на клиенте хешировать нельзя. иначе смысл вообще хешировать? смотрите в сторону JAAS

Comment: ок, мне приходит пароль при регистрации его перед сохранением надо в хеш переводить, мне приходит пароль при авторизации та же фигня, есть какие то решения в spring security ?

Comment: @AndreySibirkin а что, вам лень проверить хэш пароля при регистрации и перед авторизацией?

Comment: нет, просто возникают велосипеды в кастомной реализации авторизации ss, ну ок, спасибо

Comment: Вот пример Spring security, правда на английском  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/

Comment: тоже что то видел, правда уже незнаю в какую сторону деваться, только разобрался что в сторону бэкэнда, теперь еще возможно придется еще одну кастомную реализацию придется делать, сложно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В spring-security это предусмотрено, для того чтобы хешировать пароли приходящие от пользователей надо сконфигуривать настройки аутентификации в конфигурации WebSecurity
У меня это выглядит примерно так

```
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```